# How to concatenate variable with hard coded value inside click event in Angular4

Tags: angular

I want to add accord with value of `i` inside click event.
my same logic is working in `*ngif=""` and interpolation mark but it is not working in `(click)=""` event.

```
<div class="popCheckListDropMain" *ngFor="let srkey of srDataList; let i = index">
  <h4 (click)="'accord'+i=!'accord'+i">{{srkey.key}} </h4>
  <ul class="popCheckListDropList" *ngIf="'accord'+i">
    <li *ngFor="let list of srkey.list">
        <div class="customCheckBox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="{{list.name}}" name="{{list.name}}" [(ngModel)]="list.isSelected"
            >
            <div class="check"></div>
        </div>
        <label for="{{list.name}}" >{{list.name}} {{list.isSelected}} </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `'accord'+i =!...` is not a vliad expression

Comment: Sorry if I read this wrong but what you want to accomplish here? If you put 'accord+i' onClick() your *ngIf() will be always true?

Comment: I guess he's trying to toggle a `accord547` boolean

Comment: @Mozgor seen it.

Comment: @Swoox my comment trying to explain his expected behavior wasn't an example of clarity either :)

Comment: @Rajnish Rajput you should not use `*ngIf` for a toggled content, because it will be destroyed / created each time you toggle your boolean. Pick `[hidden]="whatever_condition"` instead to simply hide / show your `<ul>`

Comment: yes there is a loop of toggled tabs thats why i want if accord1 == true then make it false by "accord1=!accord1  and i want index instead of 1.
all i want is toggle ul on click of h4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ts, add a variable to store every item's state:

```
toggleAccordions: any = {};
```

Change you template to following:

```
<div class="popCheckListDropMain" *ngFor="let srkey of srDataList; let i = index">
  <h4 (click)="toggleAccordions['accord'+i]=!toggleAccordions['accord'+i]">{{srkey.key}} </h4>
  <ul class="popCheckListDropList" *ngIf="toggleAccordions['accord'+i]">
    <li *ngFor="let list of srkey.list">
        <div class="customCheckBox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="{{list.name}}" name="{{list.name}}" [(ngModel)]="list.isSelected"
            >
            <div class="check"></div>
        </div>
        <label for="{{list.name}}" >{{list.name}} {{list.isSelected}} </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Was writting kinda the same. Ugly as hell and not what I'd call 'best practise', but an easy way to fix OP's problem.

Comment: By the way, for a toggled content, `*ngIf` should not be used. Pick `[hidden]="whatever_condition"` instead

Comment: thanks a lot its working but I also want to know clean and proper way to do this.

Comment: @RajnishRajput this is a clean way, you have to store state of each accordion, otherwise you just have same state for all of them. Please upvote and mark accepted if it helped :)

Comment: @Mozgor `*ngIf` is recommended over `[hidden]`. Read here: https://angularjs.blogspot.de/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html

Comment: @Faisal it is a good thing to be aware of `[hidden]` limits (even if the main case, aka using `display: flex` can be easy "fixed" by relieving on `fxHide` property of `angular flex layout` ).

However, chain creating and destroying DOM elements is a huge no go. As long as you provide a toggle button, you must assume your user might toggle it many times. In this particuliar case, it is even worst given that there are **many** elements with a specific toggle bound to each of them.

`[hidden]` and `*ngIf` simply don't fulfill the same purpose and shouldn't be swapped.